# How do I run a cron job on Google App Engine immediately?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have configured Google App Engine to record exception with [ereporter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter).

The cron job is configured to run every 59 minutes. The cron.yaml is as follows

```
cron:
- description: Daily exception report
  url: /_ereporter?sender=xxx.xxx@gmail.com  # The sender must be an app admin.
  schedule: every 59 minutes
```

How to do I run this immediately.

What I am trying to do here is simulate a 500 HTTP error and see the stack trace delivered immediately via the cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the URL from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't using cron. Cron is a scheduling system, you could get it to run every minute.

Alternately you could wrap your entire handler in a try/except block and try to catch everything.  (You can do this for some DeadlineExceededErrors for instance) then fire off a task which invokes ereporter handler, and then re-raise the Exception.

However in many cases Google infrastructure can be the cause of the Error 500 and you won't be able to catch the error. To be honest you are only likely to be able to cause an email sent for a subset of all possible Error 500's.  The most reliable way probably be to have a process continuously monitor the logs, and email from there.

Mind you email isn't consider reliable or fast so a 1 min cron cycle is probably fast enough.

Comment: So I can run the cron job every minute. If not email how else can I send notifications ? Also the process you referred to for monitoring the logs, is there any examples of this ?

Comment: Email is probably good enough. If a one minute cycle on cron is fast enough for you I would go with that. My comment about email reliability is more about the fact, that it can fail too, google can have problems. If your email is going somewhere other than gmail then intermediate mail servers can have problems etc... 

The last error 500 I had was back in March.

Comment: I have noticed sometimes the cron job (every 2 minutes) ereporter does not pick up my exception and email it. I am not sure why. Yes I am on gmail, no worries there.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread as I was trying to do this as well. A (hacky) solution I found was to add a curl command at the end of my cloudbuild.yaml file that triggers the file immediately per this thread. Hope this helps!

[Make a curl request in Cloud Build CI/CD pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570335/make-a-curl-request-in-cloud-build-ci-cd-pipeline)