# Make a curl request in Cloud Build CI/CD pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I have a server where our test cases run for all API, which is on the compute engine of GCP. How can I connect it from cloud build CI/CD pipeline so that the CI/CD stage passes only on **200** response status code from the server?

GCP says to create a custom build step ([here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps)). Docs are not very clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 solutions.

- You can effectively create a custom step. Build a container, finish it by an `ENTRYPOINT` which will be invoked in the Cloud Build pipeline
- You can perform a curl call inside any steps which contain the command, get the return code and apply a condition on it (here exit if different of 200). Here an example of code

```
steps:
        - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
          entrypoint: "bash"
          args:
                  - "-c"
                  - |
                      RESPONSE=$(curl -i <YOUR URL> | grep HTTP | cut -d' ' -f2)
                      if [ "200" != "$$RESPONSE" ]; then exit 1; fi
```

*Note the double `$$` to prevent Cloud Build to look into Substitution variables*

Comment: Thanks! I saw something like gcr.io/cloud-builders/curl. Can I use /curl instead of using gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud? What's the difference between both? If I can use gcr.io/cloud-builders/curl, how would the command look like for the above task?

Comment: @DarshanNaik you can find an example on the Github repository [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/curl). Regarding the difference, they are different images and use different arguments. Find all the information regarding the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud` image [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud).

Comment: The differences are the ENTRYPOINT and the packages installed on the image you can replace the step name by `gcr.io/cloud-builders/curl` but you have to keep the entrypoint. Indeed, with the curl image if you use it directly, you perform a unary call. Here you need to perform the call and to test the HTTP response. So, you need a script and thus to have `bash` as entrypoint

Comment: Thank you I've used this to clear cloudflare cache after build with a curl request .. thank you !!

Comment: RESPONSE=$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" <YOUR URL>)
will return the status code - there will be no need for grep and cut

Answer (score 1):

```
steps:
- name: 'curlimages/curl'
  args: ['-d', '"{\"id\":\"$BUILD_ID\"}"', '-X', 'POST', 'http://www.example.com']
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/curl/README.md